# Call the API a second time and get the value obtained in the first call plus the value obtained in the second call as a result

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this API call which returns the following.

2 'cantidad original'

1 ' cantidad total recogida'

I need that when I call it again for the second time, it returns the value of QuantityCollected by adding the value that it returned in the first call.

```
anadirReserva() {
    this.api
      .gePickingOrderReserveAdd(
        this.token,
        this.userName,
        this.enterprise,
        this.warehouse,
        this.loadOrder,
        this.zone,
        this.article,
        this.tireName,
        this.zoneLocation,
        this.shelfLocation,
        this.moduleLocation,
        this.heightLocation,
        this.cantidadRecogida,
        this.internalOrder,
        this.id,
        this.quantity,
        this.errorFalta
      )
      .subscribe((responsePickingOrderReserveAdd) => {
        const { result, value } = responsePickingOrderReserveAdd;
        if (result !== 0 || !value || !value.Rows || value.Rows.length === 0) {
          this.error = 'Error, no ha devuelto datos';
          return;
        }
        console.log(this.quantity, 'cantidad original')
        console.log(this.cantidadRecogida, ' cantidad total recogida')
        if (this.quantity === this.cantidadRecogida)  {
          this.mostrarBotonConfirmacion = true;
          console.log(this.mostrarBotonConfirmacion)
        }
      });
  }
```

Help please.

Comment: Well, then you need either to rewrite your api that it returns the desired result or you need to store the result of the first call somewhere and add it to the result of the second call ...

Comment: I know that, that's what he was striving for. Save the value obtained in the first call but I don't know how to do it.